# Get-AzStorageBlob: Container name 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer' is invalid

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation

I tried to access the public blob storage container items through powershell web CLI,  but facing below issue.

Code:

```
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'muthudev' -StorageAccountKey 'QMv77eoYUQcnb1QfvGjsGOd+gg=='

$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'public' -Context $StorageContext

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $Container -Context $StorageContext
```

Error:

> Get-AzStorageBlob: Container name 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer' is invalid. Valid names start and end w
>   ith a lower case letter or a number and has in between a lower case letter, number or dash with no consecutive dashes and is 3 through 63 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting this error is because you're passing an object for `-Container` parameter however as per the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-6.13.0), it should be a string.

Please try the following:

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container 'public' -Context $StorageContext
```

or

```
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $Container.Name -Context $StorageContext
```

Comment: storage ==> public [container] ==> inside public 2 folders will be there

Web
Mob
i need to access the blob items what are things will be there inside Web folder

Comment: Please refrain from asking additional questions in comments. Instead ask a new question.